# How to create appropriate POJOs to provided JSON response?

Tags: java, json, jackson, mapping, objectmapper

community!
I got the following JSON response from some API:

```
[
    [
        [
            {
                "key": [
                    "1",
                    "test1"
                ],
                "value": 1582890257944
            },
            {
                "key": [
                    "2",
                    "test2"
                ],
                "value": 1582888081654
            },
            {
                "key": [
                    "3",
                    "test3"
                ],
                "value": 1582884771691
            }
        ]
    ]
]
```

I should create classes to map this JSON to Java classes
Previously I got the following JSON:

```
[
    {
        "key": [
            "test1"
        ],
        "value": 1
    },
    {
        "key": [
            "test2"
        ],
        "value": 2
    }
]
```

and for this JSON I've created a simple class:

```
public class SomeClass {

    private List<String> key;
    private int value;
}
```

and Jackson mapped it correct without any problems...

Please help me, what's structure I need for class/classes?
I tried to write something like that:

```
        List<String> params = new ArrayList<>();
        params.add("1");
        params.add("test1");

        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
        someClass.setKey(params);
        someClass.setValue(1L);

        List<SomeClass> arrays = new ArrayList<>();
        arrays.add(someClass);
        arrays.add(someClass);

        List<List<SomeClass>> arrayLists = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayLists.add(arrays);

        List<List<List<SomeClass>>> threeLists = new ArrayList<>();
        threeLists.add(arrayLists);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        String prettyJson = gson.toJson(threeLists);

        System.out.println(prettyJson);
```

And got the same JSON that I had from response...
Should I create class with the next structure?

```
List<List<List<String>>> key;
long value;
```

but I got error from jackson:

Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `main.entity.SomeClass` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 2, column: 5] (through reference chain: java.lang.Object[][0])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `List<List<List<String>>> key` will not work since the Json structure is `List<List<List<SomeClass>>>` as you have it in your sample code.

You can use Jackson `TypeReference` class to deserialize. Sample code using jackson-databind.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json = "[[[{\"key\":[\"1\",\"test1\"],\"value\":1},{\"key\":[\"1\",\"test1\"],\"value\":1}]]]";
    TypeReference<List<List<List<SomeClass>>>> typeRef = new TypeReference<List<List<List<SomeClass>>>>() {
    };
    try {
        List<List<List<SomeClass>>> someClassList = mapper.readValue(json, typeRef);
        System.out.println(someClassList);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works fine, but need add @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true). I think only in my case..